# Accessing nested tupels in dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm posting this question after not finding the answer in the many existing issues related to this topic.
I have a dictionary similar to this one:

`foo = {'a': [(1, 0.5), (2, 0.3)], 'b': [(3, 0.4), (4, 0.1)]}`

and would like to access the items of the nested tupels, in order to create the following dictionary out of it:

`foo = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}`

How do I go about doing this, preferably in a pythonic way?

Comment: Your desired result has invalid syntax. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these two solutions are easiest to read:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> {k:map(itemgetter(0), foo[k]) for k in foo}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

or import-less:

```
>>> {k:[x[0] for x in foo[k]] for k in foo}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about?

```
{x: map(lambda z: z[0], y) for x, y in foo.iteritems()}
```

Comment: In python3 that would be:
 {x: list(map(lambda z: z[0], y)) for x, y in foo.items()}

Answer (score 0):

Using `dict comprehension`:

```
In [214]: {key:list(map(lambda x: x[0], foo[key])) for key in foo}
Out[214]: {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{k:list(zip(x,y)[0]) for k,(x,y) in foo.iteritems()}
```

This gives:

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) from `collections` module:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k in foo:
        for v in foo[k]:
            d[k].append(v[0])
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
>>> d['a']
[1, 2]
```